# Using Tailwind in ASP.NET Core Razor page, can I use @model in calc()?

Tags: asp.net-core, tailwind-css, razor-pages

Here's my problem. I am using Razor pages and Tailwind. I want to use the `@model` expression in the tailwind syntax. In this way, I will get rid of the switch case structure. It seems to be working properly in the debug screen of the browser. But, nothing changes.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MainClassification)
{
    <button class="flex justify-center align-middle m-auto px-36 py-[calc(27rem/@Model.MainClassification.Count)]">@item</button>
}
```

The more values there are, the smaller the padding area should be. Nothing changes even though I see it correctly in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS itself does not support Razor syntax, because Razor syntax is server-side C# code, while CSS is client-side code that runs in the browser. In the browser, CSS is a static style sheet and does not support dynamic calculations or Razor syntax on the server side.

So you can using below code to implement it.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MainClassification)
{
    var paddingY = 27 / Model.MainClassification.Count; 
    <button style="padding-top: @(paddingY)rem; padding-bottom: @(paddingY)rem;" class="flex justify-center align-middle m-auto px-36">
        @item
    </button>
}
```

**Test Result**

[image]